# How do I set a default value to a combobox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a small bit of code for a combobox, and I want the default selection to be "kids". How would I do this?

```
<ComboBox Margin="10" DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:Name="categoryBox" FontSize="20">
                <ComboBox.Items>
                    <ComboBoxItem>Kids</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>Films</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>Foods</ComboBoxItem>
                </ComboBox.Items>
```

Comment: Set the `SelectedIndex`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the property SelectedIndex to 0.

```
<ComboBox Margin="10" DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:Name="categoryBox" FontSize="20" SelectedIndex = "0">
                    <ComboBox.Items>
                        <ComboBoxItem>Kids</ComboBoxItem>
                        <ComboBoxItem>Films</ComboBoxItem>
                        <ComboBoxItem>Foods</ComboBoxItem>
                    </ComboBox.Items>
```